# latex floating figure on end of chapter, not page

Tags: latex

I want my figures in Latex floating to  the end of the page but not whenever I use `\begin{figure}[b]` they end up at the end of the chapter. I have searched for this question quite a while now, but all I can find is to une `\begin{figure}[H]`. But I don't want them at exactly the place they are, but at the end of this vary page. How can I achieve that?
(I am using the float-package, but that doesn't seem to have any influence on this..)

Minimal example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{subfigure}      
\usepackage{wrapfig}        

\usepackage{graphicx}       
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter 1}
\section{Section 1}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.\\
\begin{figure}[b]
\begin{center}
\subfigure[]{\includegraphics[width=6.5cm]{pictures/picture_1.jpg}}
\subfigure[]{\includegraphics[width=6.5cm]{pictures/picture_2.jpg}}
\caption[picture placement]{this picture should be at the end of the first page}
\label{fig:label}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
\section{Section 2}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you make a [mre]? (if you need some dummy text for this, have a look at the `lipsum` package)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can insist on the bottom placement by using the `b!` floating specifier:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{subfigure}      
\usepackage{wrapfig}        

\usepackage{graphicx}       
\usepackage{float}


\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter 1}
\section{Section 1}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
\begin{figure*}[bp!]
%\begin{center}
\centering
\subfigure[]{\includegraphics[width=6.5cm]{example-image}}
\subfigure[]{\includegraphics[width=6.5cm]{example-image}}
\caption[picture placement]{this picture should be at the end of the first page}
\label{fig:label}
%\end{center}
\end{figure*}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
\section{Section 2}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
\end{document}
```

Comment: cool, thats very easy and works perfectly, thanks!